# R: Custom function in apply()

Tags: r

first time user here! I'm just learning R and have what I hope is a simple question. I have an array of numbers, nums, and I would to ensure no number is greater than one. I'm trying to do

```
myfct <- function(x) {
  if ( x > 1.0 ) x = 1.0
  return(x)
}
apply(nums, 1, myfct)
```

But I then get this error

```
Error in apply(nums, 1, myfct) : 
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! `apply` can be used only on matrices and arrays, and it looks like your `nums` is just a vector. Look at `sapply` and `lapply`. Second, though, for this and future questions, you will have a much better answer rate (greater than 0) if you first read about [minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems that `nums` is a vector.  So you can directly apply the `myfct` i.e `myfct(nums)` with changes in `myfct` like changing `if` to `ifelse`

Comment: pmin(x, 1) or x[x > 1] <- 1

Comment: I didn't realize the difference between array and vector; I assumed they were the same! Sapply works as I thought apply would. Thanks r2evans and akrun!

Comment: Roland's solution also works as I would like. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(nums, nums > 1, 1)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I would vote it up, but it seems I don't have enough rep...

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
 nums[] <- pmin(nums, 1)
```

`pmax` is a "parallelized" maximun so any values greater than 1 are replaced by 1. Might have worked without the `[]` if `nums` was an atomic vector.

Comment: This seems to do the opposite of what I want, in that all values below 1 are then set to 1. I think the pmin solution is what will work in this particular case. This newbie appreciates the help regardless!